# Why my dot key doesn't work properly in insert mode?

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me

I have installed plugins YouCompleteMe and python-mode so as to use the auto-completion when editing a python file. But when I open an `.py` file and type <kbd>.</kbd> in insert mode, the cursor does not move forward as it does in any other case. Then I type a letter and it appears **before** the dot, which makes auto-completion unavailable.

Actually this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432688/why-dot-is-not-working-properly-in-insert-mode-of-vim-editor is the same as mine. However I don't know how to tell my situation in this question, neither do I know how to send an email to the user who answered the question.

By following the answer to the question mentioned above I can not fix the problem on my computer:

When I type the command

```
imap .
```

it shows

```
i  .           *@.<C-R>=pymode#rope#complete_on_dot()<CR>
    Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/python-mode/ftplugin/python/pymode.vim
```

When I run the command

```
iunmap .
```

it just says

```
E31: No such mapping
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: It looks like youcompleteme messes with your configuration, their [FAQ](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#is-there-some-sort-of-ycm-mailing-list-i-have-questions) suggests that use [this mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/ycm-users) to ask questions, maybe you'll find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else stumbling upon this; the reason why `:iunmap` didn't work is found in `:help E31`:

```
- If the mapping is buffer-local you need to use ":unmap <buffer>".
```

YouCompleteMe seems to just set everything buffer-locally (after all, why shouldn't it?).

When vim throws an error message like `E31: No such mapping`, you should always take a peek at the relevant help number. They're extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I copied a `.vimrc` file to my computer from another computer where the auto-completion works. It turned out that `.vimrc` works on my computer, so the problem is fixed.

However I have lost my original `.vimrc`, hence I can not give an explanation.